# Creating a c++ Program to execute other programs in qnx

Tags: c++, qnx

I am trying to write a program in `c++` for `QNX` which executes other programs.

For this I have 4 files to be handled.

```
file1
file2.l
file3.c
file4.bin
```

The algorithm is

```
if file1 is not present then execute file2.l
Execute file3.c
Execute file4.bin
```

This is the code which I have tried.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostrea>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("file1");
    if(!ifile){
  //      system("Code to run file2.l program in termnal")

    }

   // system("Code to run file3.c program in termnal")
    system("./file4.bin")
```

I need to know how to execute `file2.l` and `file3.c` using `c++` in `QNX`

Answer (score 1):

System() is only for executing system functions, such as 'cp' or 'shutdown'.
To launch a program, you can use spawn() or spawnv() functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline bool fileCheck(const string &name)
{
    if (FILE *file = fopen(name.c_str(), "r"))
    {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // Replace with your own code

    if (fileCheck("time.exe"))
    {
        // exists...
        system("swap.exe");
    }
    else
    {
        // doesn't exists...
        system("swap.exe");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program firstly creates an inline function to check the existence of a file in a fast way and then the main() occurs which does your required works.